# Why does SecPKCS12Import automatically add SecIdentities to the Keychain?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, ssl, keychain

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157-CH1g-SW35) on SecPKCS12Import states the following:

> […] You can then use the Keychain Services API (see Keychain Services
>   Reference) to put the identities and associated certificates in the
>   keychain.

This means that the items returned in the “items” argument (3rd argument of that function) should not be automatically added to the keychain. However, I have found that those items are automatically added to the keychain when using that function. If I try to add them using SecItemAdd, I get errSecDuplicateItem.

Is this a bug or should it be this way? Why are the items automatically added?

Here is some sample code:

```
NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"password", (id)kSecImportExportPassphrase, nil];
CFArrayRef items_ = NULL;
OSStatus ret = SecPKCS12Import((CFDataRef)pkcs12data /* get this from somewhere … */, (CFDictionaryRef)options, &items_);
```

If you use that code and then open Keychain Access, you’ll see that the certificate and the private key have been added to the keychain.

Regards,
David.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like Apple's documentation may be out of date for that link (SecPKCS12Import), because this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1745/_index.html mentions that "reading in a PKCS#12-formatted blob and then importing the contents of the blob into the app's keychain using the function SecPKCS12Import..."

Going by the document revision dates, QA1745 is more recent than the Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference.

Comment: You may want to ask a new question rather than posting an answer on an existing one.

Comment: Edited to remove the question at the end

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a bug or should it be this way?

It isn't a bug, the documentation is only incorrect. Well, it is correct for iOS, it is just incorrect for macOS.

> Why are the items automatically added?

This is caused by the way how this function is implemented in macOS. The comments in [the implementation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_keychain/libsecurity_keychain-55050.9/lib/SecImportExport.c) reveal the cause:

```
// SecPKCS12Import is implemented on Mac OS X in terms of the existing
// SecKeychainItemImport API, which supports importing items into a
// specified keychain with initial access control settings for keys.
```

`SecPKCS12Import` in macOS is just a wrapper around `SecKeychainItemImport` and as the function name implies, this function imports into a keychain. This also explains the following code:

```
if (!importKeychain) {
    // SecKeychainItemImport requires a keychain, so use default
    status = SecKeychainCopyDefault(&importKeychain);
}
```

On iOS the function is implemented standalone and not as a wrapper since `SecKeychainItemImport` isn't even available on iOS.

But there is a way round that if that is a problem for you. Many people work around it by creating a temporary keychain, which will never be visible to the system or the user (and thus also not be visible to apps or in Keychain Access), of course, this will work too, but is a bit of an ugly hack.

Better: Use `SecItemImport` and as import format use `kSecFormatPKCS12`, then you also get the parsed identities but nothing is imported anywhere unless you request that.

Answer (score -1):

`SecPKCS12Import` does NOT add items to the keychain.  However, it WILL look in the keychain to see if imported items are already there.  If it finds existing items, they will be returned for the `SecIdentityRef (SecCertificateRef and SecKeyRef)`.  This is why you can get `errSecDuplicateItem` when calling `SecItemAdd` after calling `SecPKCS12Import`.

When debugging, you might want to remove everything in your keychain using code like this:

```
void _EraseKeychain()
{
    NSMutableArray *toDelete = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *classes = @[(__bridge id)kSecClassCertificate,
                         (__bridge id)kSecClassKey,
                         (__bridge id)kSecClassIdentity,
                         (__bridge id)kSecClassInternetPassword,
                         (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword];
    NSMutableDictionary *query = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    query[(id)kSecClass] = (__bridge id)kSecClassIdentity;
    query[(id)kSecMatchLimit] = (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitAll;
    query[(id)kSecReturnPersistentRef] = @YES;
    id class;
    for( class in classes )
    {
        query[(__bridge id)kSecClass] = class;
        CFTypeRef items = nil;
        OSStatus result = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, &items);
        if( result == errSecSuccess )
        {
            [toDelete addObjectsFromArray:(__bridge NSArray*)items];
            CFRelease(items);
        }
    }
    id deleteRef;
    for( deleteRef in toDelete )
    {
        NSString *objectKind = @"unknown";
        if( CFGetTypeID(deleteRef) == CFDataGetTypeID() )
        {
            objectKind = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)[(__bridge NSData*)deleteRef bytes]];
        }
        NSDictionary *delRequest = @{(id)kSecValuePersistentRef:deleteRef};
        OSStatus deleteResult = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)delRequest);
        if( deleteResult == errSecSuccess )
            NSLog(@"Deleted item(%@) with persistent ref %@", objectKind, deleteRef);
        else if( deleteResult == errSecItemNotFound )
            NSLog(@"Already deleted item(%@) with persistent ref %@", objectKind, deleteRef);
        else
            NSLog(@"Can't delete keychain item(%@) with persistent ref %@", objectKind, deleteRef);
    }
}
```

Comment: A `SecIdentityRef` is an alias to a certificate/key pair.  If you delete it, you will delete the certificate and key that match it.  If you delete the certificate and key, then the `SecIdentityRef` will be invalidated.

Comment: You can clearly see in https://opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_keychain/libsecurity_keychain-55050.9/lib/SecImportExport.c that SecPKCS12Import does import into the keychain, and in fact there is no way to prevent it when using this function.